# How to set "fast mode" in low cost DRO

Tags: sensors

I have this cheap DRO from Amazon/China
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00E7XFF5Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E7XFF5Q)

I'm able to read the values out of it using a small FPGA.
The documentation says the update rate can be as fast as every 20 ms if it's in fast mode, but it doesn't say how to enable fast mode.  Currently the output is only every ~125 ms.

I've tried long-pressing the zero and inch/mm buttons, and various combinations of buttons (including power) but there is no change in mode.  There are no other buttons.  There is no input wire for example to send a command.

Does someone know how to get this thing into fast mode?

thanks

Comment: questions about the use of a commercial product are off topic here .... try contacting the seller to obtain a datasheet

Comment: This is not just "a" commercial product, but a class of commercial products, i.e. "cheap Chinese DROs", of which there any many instances.  It falls into the category of generic sensor measurement stuff which I would have thought would be in line with a robotics forum, not too disparate from "how do I read SPI" or "does UART go MSB or LSB first", etc.

Comment: SPI has standards, so most questions can be answered ... how to change mode on an unknown device cannot be answered ... it is incredible that you would think that it falls into a generic measurement realm